# Homebrewing and Cats

Tags: sanitation, cleaning

I am somewhat interested in obtaining 2 kittens.

My 1 bedroom apartment already isn't the cleanest. I spray 409 and Windex on all my surfaces before I brew or bottle and call it clean. I'm not going to spend any time picking up cat hair.

If I greatly prefer homebrewing to animals, should I abandon all hope for a pair of cats? What methods exist to minimize the damage from animals to homebrewing in a one bedroom apartment?

I extract brew now but intend on moving to full-grain in the next 3-6 months.

Comment: I have 3 cats - they don't interfere with brewing.

Comment: Just keep them from jumping in the kettle and you should be fine. I have 2 cats and they don't really care when I'm brewing

Comment: You should make it more clear that you are not spraying your brewing gear with 409/Windex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had 5-6 cats and 2 dogs for the entire 16 years I've been homebrewing.  They are no bigger threat to your beer than you yourself are.  Use StarSan in a spray bottle to clean things, not toxic cleaners like 409 and Windex.

Comment: I only use 409/Windex for surfaces, not for equipment.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be wary of using 409 or Windex for brewing purposes; find some proper homebrew-friendly cleaners and sanitizers (oxiclean free and star-san are awesome).

There's no inherent incompatibility between homebrewing and pets.  You might have to keep curious cats away from some brewing processes/steps, but if you're keeping proper sanitation and your head about you, everything will be fine.  What are you concerned about, in particular?

Comment: Oh I use Star-san my sanitizing my brewing equipment; I just use 409/Windex to spray down the counters and floor. I am concerned about the cat's infecting the beer somehow (maybe I should dunk them in star san? :) ) and concerned about cat hair drifting into the brew.

Comment: Your worries are baseless.  Enjoy your cats and your homebrew.

Answer (score 1):

Note: Not directly related but worth noting
DOGS are generally allergic to hops, gives them sore skin. I don't know if the same is for cats.

---

Correction: 
 hyperthermia (overheating can result in death)

Comment: Dogs suffer malignant hyperthermia from hops.  I've never heard anything about skin problems.

Comment: I'll accept that over my response. My reference could be localised to specific dog and a skin allergy.

Comment: Dogs suffer hyperthermia from spent hops.

Answer (score 0):

Your cats shouldnt be a problem. Just maintain a clean brew-space. My cat was hanging out with me last time I was bottling. She was very curious, but I kept her away from my bucket & bottles.